# Connect to MySql db from LoadRunner

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner

I have MySql server installed locally (left default settings) and can't figure it out how to load it using HP LoadRunner. I'm using lr_db_connect method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need an ODBC driver for MySQL to get from A (LoadRunner Virtual User) to B (MySQL Database).  Do you have one installed, configured, tested independent of LoadRunner, that you are using?

## #ClientArchitecture #LoadrunnerInterfaces